# From SQL Server to MONGODB: design problem

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

For the first time I want to see other database than SQL Server for my development.

MongoDB is a good alternative for my project.

What is difficult to understand is "the design" of MONGODB for me.

User (table)

```
Id
Name
Address
```

Friends (table)

```
IdUser
IdFriends
```

With this SQL table, I want to allow an user to became a friend of other user like Facebook.

Which is the best design for MongoDB?

Answer (score 3):

Consider nesting friends ids inside `User` document:

```
{
    _id: 7,
    name: "Johnny",
    address: "Acme St.",
    friends: [8, 9, 15]
}
```

On one hand you don't need joins to fetch friends (at least ids), because everything is nested within a single document and the schema looks more pleasant. On the other - to fetch the actual friends, you hit N+1 problem. However fetching by id is rather cheap, also consider caching.

Comment: Ok, suppose that i have 1.000 or 10.000 friends?

Comment: MongoDB document size limit is 16 MiB ([SERVER-431](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-431)), also there are operations to work with nested arrays without fetching whole array itself.